# How I run the function in exactly 0.43 second in python?

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I have a question. I have the function to run the EV3 motor.

```
def motor_decrease(speed_decrease):
    left_motor.run(speed=left_motor.speed() - speed_decrease) 
    right_motor.run(speed=right_motor.speed() - speed_decrease )
```

So i want to run the function in 0,43s each i invoke the function. How can i solve the problem to run like that ?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Are you trying to decelerate smoothly?

Comment: while python isn't a "realtime" language, it does have https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep If the actual sleep time wasn't exact, you can get the time and compensate later.

Comment: computers are not working like that, I think the actual run time can not be exactly calculated. Probably you can get how many CPU ticks it passed during the execution, and that depends on how the cpus, memorys, hard drives are working, and a lot of other things

I think you can add time.sleep(0.42999second) to the code and try best to figure out a proper waiting time on certain machines

Comment: If you are using pybricks, you can also import the `wait()` function by doing: `from pybricks.tools import wait` and call `wait(43)` at the start of each function